Weirdly big spacing around ε character
For some reason my ϵ (\[Epsilon]) character has a lot of empty space above and below it. It's best described by a screenshot here.
.
ε (\[CurlyEpsilon]) seems to be fine, however ϱ (\[CurlyRho]) has the same problem. The FullForm of the example in the screenshot is as you would expect it:
Times[Power[a,-1],Plus[1,a],Power[b,-1],Power[c,-1],ϵ,Plus[1,ϵ]]

It also does not make a difference if I put it in via "esc e esc" or type in "ϵ" directly.
I'm running Mathematica 14 on Arch Linux.
Does someone have the same problem and managed to fix it?

Does not happen on v14.0 on Windows, so might be platform specific.

Spacing is as expected with v14 on a Mac

The exact issue on Arch Linux has been observed by someone else: Extra large brackets with greek letters in Mathematica 14.
